# Anylogic: How can you link a population with a source

Tags: anylogic

how is it possible that the sourceof a process model only creates the agents out of a population and in best case at once? In my model the source is creating more agents than the size of the population.
thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Source it is not possible to output already existing Agents of a population from it, as the source is always creating them at the time of output.

You have two possibilities:

1. Instead of a Source, use the Process Modelling element **Enter** at
   the start of your process flow. Using the function
   `enter.take(myPopulation.get(index))` you can input your already
   existing population members. This way you can also input them "at once".
2. In the Source properties under *Advanced - Population* select your
   custom population. Whenever the source creates a new Agent, it will
   get added to this population. Note: The Agent type of the population
   must be the same as the Agent type defined in the Source.